# Calling jython script from java

Tags: java, jython

I am currently working on a simple hello world program using jython and java.

The program is designed in way that a jython method accepts a name parameter and returns welcome message.

My problem is whenever I am accessing the jython method from java, it shows **nullponter exception**

My jython Script (JythonHello.py):

```
class JythonHello:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   
    def sayHello(self):
        return "Hello "+ self.name
```

and my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    interpreter.execfile("src/jython/JythonHello.py");

    PyObject callFunction = interpreter.get("sayHello");
    PyObject result = callFunction.__call__(new PyString("Boban"));
    String msg = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
    System.out.println("output: " + msg);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Add the exception stack trace. And just for the record: you are sure that "src/...." is a valid path from where you call your java main?

Comment: it shows only java.lang.NullPointerException. I am not sure about the path.Is there any other way of loading script file?

Comment: But fore sure there are line numbers, method names?!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javaSide.JavaClass.main(JavaClass.java:16)

Comment: error in PyObject result = callFunction.__call__(new PyString("Boban"));

Comment: Minor indentation changes

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code; your python code defines a class and a member method:

```
class JythonHello:
  def __init__(self, name): ...
  def sayHello(self): ...
```

And it seems that you intend to call **that** method:

```
 PyObject callFunction = interpreter.get("sayHello");
 PyObject result = callFunction.__call__(new PyString("Boban"));
```

But please note: `sayHello()` doesn't take **any** arguments. That self parameter is an indication that you have to call it on an object; but without any other parameters!

So, in pure python you would say:

```
helloVar = JythonHello("Boban")
helloVar.sayHello()
```

But your java code tries to call it like

```
sayHello("Boban")
```

So, the real answer is: step back; and re-think what you **really** intend to do; and then write code that works that way.

I would start by not adding the "class" part on the python side; instead try to **simply** invoke a function that takes a string argument for example!

And finally: could it be that you are on the wrong path altogether? The **main** point of jython is to write simply python code to do "debug" work within a running JVM. You are writing complicated Java code to use a bit of python code on the other hand ...

Comment: I thought if you've got something like Java - harder, but more efficient + Python - easier, less efficient, the idea is implementing core features in Java, and writing extensions in Python, so, are you really sure the main point of jython is debbugging ?

Comment: @user7185318 Well, it is in *my* context ;-)